# How to mention Mac Home folder in yaml file

Tags: python, macos, yaml

Can someone tell me how to mention Mac Home folder in yaml file?

I have a settings.yaml file that I use in my Python code to connect to GDrive. It exports the credentials to a JSON file and I want that to extract to GDrive folder in Home directory.

**settings.yaml**

```
    client_config_backend: 'settings'
    client_config:
      client_id: "something"
      client_secret: "something"
      auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
      token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

    save_credentials: True
    save_credentials_backend: 'file'
    save_credentials_file: '/Users/machinename/GDrive/credentials.json'
```

And in the python file, it is mentioned like this:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth(settings_file='settings.yaml')
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile('/Users/machinename/GDrive/credentials.json')
```

So, different people will run this in different machines and the `machinename` will vary, so I am trying to provide the dynamic version for Home directory. I tried `~/GDrive/credentials.json` but it did not work.

Can someone help how to declare home directory in the yaml file?

Comment: Typically, the tilde should work on all systems `~` or `~/` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The home folder is denoted as `~`.
The problem is you need to expand, and you can do by using `os`:

```py
import os

os.path.expanduser("~/GDrive/credentials.json")
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to store it in the yaml code, it's the same thing:

**settings.yaml**

```
client_config_backend: 'settings'
client_config:
  client_id: "something"
  client_secret: "something"
  auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
  token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

save_credentials: True
save_credentials_backend: 'file'
save_credentials_file: '~/GDrive/credentials.json'
```

Then, in the python:

```
credentials_file = "settings.yaml"
with open(credentials_file, "r") as f:
    credentials_info = yaml.load(f)
gauth = GoogleAuth(settings_file=credentials_file)
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(os.path.expanduser(credentials_info['save_credentials_file'))
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the Python code. In Python, I can mention ~. I am trying to find a way to mention HOME directory in `save_credentials_file` of settings.yaml file.

Comment: @Sam YAML is just data. Whatever code loads the YAML needs to do the expansion. So if you're loading the data with Python, you just use this approach on the loaded data.

Comment: Exactly like @flyx said, you can keep the data in the yaml with the tilde (`~`) and in. the python code, like I wrote, expand it to the full user directory path

Comment: @Zionsof - I tried what you said, but still the `credentials.json` file was not generated inside the Home's Drive folder. I got the below error message.  Any suggestions?


/project/directory/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access /Users/machinename/GDrive/credentials.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))

Comment: From the code it seems you're trying to load, not save, and of course if you think you're generating and it's actually loading it won't exist. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes I am trying to load `settings.yaml` file that contains my google auth information. That yaml file will generate the son file mentioned in `save_credentials_file` and the son file then used to perform auth. If you didn't provide any path (and just file name) then the son file will be generated on the current running directory, but I am trying to redirect the location of the file to a particular directory instead of default directory.

Comment: What would be different though? Just do the same with both paths, keeping the `~` and use `os.path.expanduser`

Answer (score 0):

This may achieve what you wanted

```
In settings.yaml
    save_credentials_file: '$HOME/GDrive/credentials.json'
...
In python, put '$HOME/GDrive/credentials.json' into variable save_credentials_file,

gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(os.path.expandvars(save_credentials_file))
```

Comment: Just like the above comment, I tried what you said, but still the `credentials.json` file was not generated inside the Home's Drive folder. I got the below error message. Any suggestions? `/project/directory/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access /Users/machinename/GDrive/credentials.json: No such file or directory warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))`